# What is the desktop plugin for lotus same time chat agent?

Tags: lotus-notes, chat, lotus-sametime

I have Lotus Notes and SameTime chat installed. I have heard that there is a desktop SameTime chat plug-in, which when installed, will enable me to open up the same time chat, without first opening the Lotus Notes mail client. Does anybody have any more information about this? If so, where can I download and install it from?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the standalone IBM Sametime client. With a Notes and Domino license you are entitled to use IBM Sametime Entry which includes the standalone Sametime desktop client: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/notesanddomino/additionalswentitlements.html

The IBM Sametime client is part of the IBM Sametime Entry package available on IBM Passport Advantage. This document can help with part numbers: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24029130

Comment: I have notes 8.5 . If i upgrade this one, will i be able to install the stand alone client ?

Comment: Yes, you can have both Notes and the standalone Sametime client installed.

Answer (score 1):

[Pidgin Instant Messenger](http://pidgin.im/) has the ability to connect with the SameTime network, this could work as a standalone chat client.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the standalone but if you are already using notes, you should use the internal one to save memory, since the standalone and notes both load a huge instance of the eclipse framework.